# How to execute something in an activity from a non-activity class?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am executing something in an async class(from activity A), and before the result comes I start another activity B. 
Now I want to execute a block of code in B based on result from the async class.

I couldn't find a proper solution over the internet. Thus posting it here.

Answer (score 0):

Define your own `MyApp extends Application` class and declare it in your manifest as `<application android:name="mypackage.MyApp></application>`

Then have a public field `myResult` in your My App. Then you can store your result and get your result from that public field as `((MyApp)getApplication()).myResult`

This is because `MyApp` singleton object exists all the time your app is running.

If you want *notification* you can use an event bus such as [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/)

Or you can just send a broadcast and catch it by a broadcast receiver in your other activity..

Comment: I want to notify the new activity when some task completes in my non-activity class. How will this help solve this problem?

Comment: If you want to send notification use event bus such as Otto. See my edited answer. Or maybe you just can send a broadcast and catch it by a broadcast receiver in your other activity.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of possible solutions to do this. Let me add my favourites:

1. Event Bus (Square's Otto or GreenDroid's one). In this case you need to subscribe your activity to get the result.
2. Loaders - native android solution, no libs needed. To cook this one you need to use content provider, which contains the table with results and in your async task there should be a method to insert result into db.